# solutions of $x^2\equiv 1 \pmod p $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If p is a prime, show that the only solutions of  $x^2\equiv 1 \pmod p $ are $x=1$ and $x\equiv -1 \pmod p$. (from herstein's abstract algebra chapter2 section4 lagrange's theorem problem 15, this section is unfamiliar to me, and the questions are all damned hard!)

Comment: This is the umpteenth time this question is being asked. I would like to know the reason why a veteran of the site does not recognize this as a duplicate without further ado.

Comment: @Jyrk It is not easy to search for *equations* on SE, so for questions like this it is often much easier to ask/answer than to locate a prior duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $x^2 = 1$ if and only if $(x-1)(x+1)=0$.

Comment: I did notice that, but then I didn't know what to do next and stucked.

Comment: @pxc3110 Which elements of $\mathbb{Z}/p$ are zero divisors?

Comment: "zero divisors?" what's that please?

Comment: @pxc3110 $x$ is a zero divisor if there is a $y \neq 0$ with $xy = 0$. Note that you deal with an equation of the form $xy = 0$ so in order to answer your question you have to determine all zero divisors of the corresponding ring (i.e. $\mathbb{Z}/p$).

Comment: thanks. But if you're using ring theory, I think there might be some other ways of solving this, which is more easy for me to understand right now.

Comment: @pxc3110: This is group theory. What Dune tries to explain you is that because $p$ is prime, then if $xy = 0 \mod p$, then $x = 0 \mod p$ or $y = 0\mod p$. If $p$ is not prime, then this is not true anymore. Try with $4$ if you want.

Comment: @user88595 Thank you for your explanation. But that "or" in "x=0 mod or y=0 mod" doesn't sound good. I'm asked to prove x=0mod and y=0mod and they should be the only solutions

Comment: @pxc3110: You can't have $x = 1$ **and** $x = -1$ can you? You need to understand carefully: the reasoning I end with is $x = 1$ **or** $x = -1$. This implies that both are solutions, but they are not solutions together. $1$ and $-1$ are solutions but $x = 1$ and $x = -1$ isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

> If a prime divides a product of integers then it divides at least one of the factors.

If $x$ is a solution of $x^2\equiv 1\pmod p$, apply this factlet to $(x-1)(x+1)$.